# PhoneGap Build WP8 Silverlight SDK

Tags: silverlight, cordova, windows-phone-8

Trying a local build of PhoneGap for Windows Phone 8 on a Windows 8.1 machine. PhoneGap version 3.4.0.

Using:

phonegap local build wp8

The build platform is set in the project to X86.

Get the error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.WindowsPhon
>   e.Common.targets(110,5): error : The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed.

But it is installed. In the project I added to the reference paths:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\

Still get the error. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get the same error, but when I tried to install the Silverlight 4 SDK it told me a newer version of it already exists.

Comment: I resolved it by installing the Visual Studio Preview for  PhoneGap which somehow solved the problem.

Comment: If you're running VS2013 then you need to modify the install and select WP8 SDK http://stackoverflow.com/a/28781318/222748. For VS2012 just download and install the WP8.0 SDK from here https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk.