# How to install WP 8.0 SDK if WP 8.1 SDK is installed?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sdk, installation, windows-phone-8.1

I have the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK on my dev pc installed together with VS 2013. I need to open some WP 8.0 projects in VS 2013, but I can't do that without having WP 8.0 SDK installed.

However, when I try to install it from the local ISO, I have the following installation error:

** Setup Blocked **
The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer.

[image]

Do I need to remove the WP 8.1 SDK just to install WP 8.0 SDK and then install WP 8.1 SDK again? Is this the only way, and will it really help?

It seems I need to install the older SDK as I cannot launch my WP 8.0 projects because of this error I get when I open them:

[image]

Comment: You *can* open WP8.0 projects with WP SDK 8.1, so you don't need to do this.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts, I get this error: "Unable to open the <project_name> project. To open a Windows Phone project, you must install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0". That's why I asked my question on SO!

Comment: It should work - but there may be a problem with your VS2013 install then. What edition are you using (Express/Pro etc)?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts, I'm using VS Community 2013 now. Installed it instead of VS 2013 Pro a week ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the VS2013 install in "Program and Features" and select "Windows Phone 8.0 SDK".

[image]

Comment: That was really helpful.. error messages in VS were just not helpful at all, leading to a download link for WP SDK 8 that seems to only install into VS 2012. I got "unable to open the project to open a windows phone project, you must install the windows phone sdk 8.0" in case someone googles for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 8.1 came up with the Update 2 for Visual Studio, you should be able to open a WP8 application using VS 2013 8.1 update.

reference: [Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

[How to get started with windows phone SDK 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125570/)

Comment: It should, but I see the contrary... Do you want me to mark your answer as "not useful"?